# Can the following IF-ELSE block be compressed into a single IF statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, logical-operators

I have the following `if-else` block:

```
boolean condA = false, condB = true;

if (!condA) {
    // do WORK_C
} else {
    if (condB) {
        // do WORK_C
    }
}
```

While writing this up, I realized that I am doing the same work in both condition matches. I wonder if this can be compressed any further.

I'm willing to provide more info/context, should it be required.

Comment: I think you want to do like `if (!condA || condB)` .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you try to verbally express the condition under which you want to perform `WORK_C` you will say something along the lines of "if condA is false or if condB is true". This is precisely what you want to write in your `if` statement:

```java
if (!condA || condB) {
    // do WORK_C
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I did come up with `if (!condA || condB)`. But, for some reason, I could not justify it. Thanks again for the affirmative answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use logical operators **&& / ||** in place of multiple if else statements. e.g

```
boolean condA = false, condB = true;

if (!condA || condB) {
    // do WORK_C
}
```

The **OR (||)** operator gives the ability to have an if statement to be true if only one out of several conditions is met.

Comment: Thank you, I did come up with `if (!condA || condB)`. But, for some reason, I could not justify it. Thanks again for the affirmative answer. The only reason I chose to mark Ishamael's answer is that s/he posted it before. Its sad that we have to choose _one_ correct answer, since both of you have been excellent help.